# Open iCloud document when network not available

Tags: icloud

Since `URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:` returns non-nil even in Airplane mode as long as iCloud remains signed in, how can I detect if the network is available and process accordingly?

If I blindly open a document whose content was not cached locally (I see it because its metadata is there) and the network is not available, the loading process will never complete.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are attributes for the `NSMetadataItem`s that tell you whether a file is downloaded. Check the attribute `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey`. You can compare that to the string `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusCurrent` on iOS 7 to determine whether the file is downloaded already.

There is more code in [this](https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles/blob/master/Framework/Source/Cloud%20File%20Systems/CDEICloudFileSystem.m) class of the Ensembles project which may help you further with the metadata query attributes you need. (Eg. the attributes for older iOS versions are a bit different.)

Disclosure: I develop the Ensembles project.

Comment: But if you check `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey` before making a call to `openWithCompletionHandler:`, you also need to check whether network connection is available. Good news is, `openWithCompletionHandler:` DOES get to completion by invoking `completionHandler`, with `success=NO`, not too long after.